# Locking mutex by multiple subprocesses

Tags: python, linux

Is the mutex doing it's job in this code? i.e is the sys.stdout.write protected?

```
import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock

class ParentApp():
    mutex=Lock()
    def report(self,msg):
        with ParentApp.mutex:
            sys.stdout.write(msg)

class ChildApp1(ParentApp):
    def print_report(self):
        for i in xrange(100):
            ParentApp.report(self, 'BLABLA')


class ChildApp2(ParentApp):
    def print_report(self):
        for i in xrange(100):
            ParentApp.report(self, 'TESTTEST')

def runnable(app):
    app.print_report()

def main():
    app=[]
    app.append(ChildApp1())
    app.append(ChildApp2())

    pool = Pool(len(apps))
    pool.map(runnable, apps)

    exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

PS: code is also here : http://pastebin.com/GyV3w45F

PS: I am running on a Linux host

Comment: It is, run it :) also, please let me know what is weird in this code, maybe it is the source of my problems

Comment: What job did you expect it to do? Add a newline on the end of each report and run it again.

Comment: @Kam The code you pasted definitely won't run. `if __main__ == "__main__"` should be `if __name__ == "__main__"`, and you switch between `app` and `apps` for your list of objects.

Comment: Don't you need to actually use the mutex? i.e. add `with ParentApp.mutex:` to `report`?

Comment: @Dark Falcon, I don't understand your comment sorry

Comment: @Kam, If you were trying to make sure that the output of your subprocesses is not interspersed, no, that doesn't do it. Change `'BLABLA'` to `'BLABLA\n'` and `'TESTTEST'` to `'TESTTEST\n'` and you'll see this.

Comment: @Dark Falcon, I see!!! I tried it and output is not interspersed ! How can I fix this and what is going on?

Comment: Why not just use `with self.mutex`?

Comment: Well because the mutex needs to be shared between processes no?

Comment: Also, Why the down vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only doing it's job if you're on a Posix-like platform. If you're on Windows, each process ends up with a completely different copy of the lock.

You can see this by adding a little extra tracing and a `sleep` statement:

```
class ParentApp():
    mutex=Lock()
    def report(self,msg):
        print("\nGETTING for {}".format(msg))
        with self.mutex:
            print("GOT for {}".format(msg))
            sys.stdout.write(msg)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(5)
```

On Linux:

```
GETTING for BLABLA
GOT for BLABLA
BLABLA
GETTING for TESTTEST
< 5 second delay here>
```

On Windows:

```
GETTING for BLABLA
GOT for BLABLA
BLABLA
GETTING for TESTTEST
GOT for TESTTEST
TESTTEST
<5 second delay here>
```

This is because Posix platforms create new processes using `os.fork()` which means the `Lock()` you created in the parent process gets automatically inherited by the children. However, Windows doesn't have `os.fork`, so it needs to spawn a new process, then re-import your module in the child. Re-importing the module means `ParentApp` gets re-imported and re-executed, and so does `Lock` class attribute. So, your parent and two children each end up with their own unique `Lock`.

To fix this, you need to create a single `Lock` in the parent, and pass that to the children. This is actually not a trivial task with your current architecture - you're passing the `Lock` object as an argument to `pool.map`, which won't allow you to pass `Lock` objects. You'll get an exception if you try it:

```
RuntimeError: Lock objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

You can only pass normal `Lock` objects to children at the point you're actually *starting* a `Process`. Once they're started (like they are when you call a `Pool` method), you get that exception:

```
l = Lock()
p = Process(target=func, args=(l,)) # ok
p.start()

pool = Pool()
pool.apply(func, args=(l,)) # not ok, raises an exception.
```

In order to pass a `Lock` to a `Pool` function like `map`, you need to use a `multiprocessing.Manager` to create a shared lock. Here's what I would recommend doing:

```
import sys 
from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock, get_context, Manager
import time

class ParentApp():
    def __init__(self, mutex):
        self.mutex = mutex

    def report(self,msg):
        with self.mutex:
            sys.stdout.write(msg)

class ChildApp1(ParentApp):
    def print_report(self):
        for i in range(100):
            ParentApp.report(self, 'BLABLA')


class ChildApp2(ParentApp):
    def print_report(self):
        for i in range(100):
            ParentApp.report(self, 'TESTTEST')

def runnable(app):
    app.print_report()

def main():
    apps=[]
    m = Manager()
    lock = m.Lock()
    apps.append(ChildApp1(lock))
    apps.append(ChildApp2(lock))

    pool = Pool(len(apps))
    pool.map(runnable, apps)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

In order to make sure the `Lock` is shared, we need to have `ParentApp` actually take the lock object as an argument. This isn't a nice as having it entirely self-contained in the class, but I think that's the best we can do with the limitations of Windows.

Comment: thank you so much for this explanation, I am actually running on Linux, I didn't think it would make any difference

Comment: @Kam Your code should actually work ok on Linux. Try adding the `sleep` inside the locked block to see for yourself.

Comment: @Kam: you could use `set_start_method('spawn')` (Python 3.4+) on Linux, to emulate the Windows behaviour. It might be simpler to make the lock global and pass it via Pool()'s `initargs` parameter to the worker processes. `def init(lock_): global lock; lock=lock_`